# why angularjs ng-include breaks 'bootstrap-switch'

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a switch to my partial view, it works as long as I am not switching the views using the ng-include. any idea why its breaking?

example in the [***plnkr code***](http://plnkr.co/edit/dw2T6YphLYU9DJi4smvz?p=preview)

basically this is what i am doing there:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="RootController">
      {{MyText}} : {{subview}}
        <button ng-click="SelectAdmin()">Administration</button>                
        <button ng-click="SelectOperation()">Operations[Breaks!]</button> 
        <br/>

        <div ng-switch="subview">
          <div ng-switch-when="operations">
              <div ng-include src="'./_partial.htm'"></div>
          </div>  
          <div ng-switch-when="administration">
            SHOWING :{{subview}}
            <div class="make-switch switch-large">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**EDIT 1**

To describe the issue a bit more:
When I start the page, I show the div that is not in the partial. i,e, set the subview = admionistrator and see an views as below.

[image]

now when i click on the "Operations" button i switch the view but use ng-include to load the partial view. and the partial view is actually showing the same content, but the view is messed up as seen in the image below.
[image]

Now even when i switch back to the earlier view by clicking on the Administrator button the make-switch is still broken.
[image]

Comment: @musically_ut : i have a link to the problem ['plnkr code'], when you click on the Operations button, the switch below breaks!

Comment: @musically_ut : thanks, i have added some screen capture of the issue.

Comment: Kiran, I think this might answer your question (I have a similar problem): http://stackoverflow.com/a/32639059/24190