# AngularJS - ngBind and Bootstrap Switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to insert HTML for a Bootstrap Switch radio button (http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) from an AngularJS controller using ngBind.  Bootstrap Switch radio buttons that are already in the HTML work when I run

$('.bs-switch').bootstrapSwitch();

But the radio button I insert into the HTML via ngBind stays a simple radio button.  I think it's a timing issue.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- this doesn't get converted to a Bootstrap Switch radio button -->
<div ng-bind-html="exampleHTML"></div>

<!-- this does get converted -->
<input type="checkbox" class="bs-switch" name="my-checkbox2" checked>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.exampleHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(
       '<input type="checkbox" class="bs-switch" ' +
       '       name="my-checkbox1" checked>'
);

$('.bs-switch').bootstrapSwitch();
```

If I do something like the following in the controller, the radio button inserted via ngBind gets converted to a Bootstrap Switch - this is why I think it's a timing issue:

```
$scope.exampleHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(
    '<input type="checkbox" class="bs-switch" ' +
    '       name="my-checkbox1" checked>'
);

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.bs-switch').bootstrapSwitch();
}, 1000);
```

Any suggestion on how to do this (in a better way than using a timeout)?  I'm trying to build a dynamic form that is generated programmatically from a JSON config file, which is why I'm using ngBind to insert HTML.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/billb123/nnkypoy9/15/)

Comment: Why do you have to insert the HTML that way?  The mantra for Angular is not to manipulate the DOM from controllers.

Comment: can you post a plunkr or something?, but I assume that you want to catch the checkbox checked event or change and then hide the checkbox and show the bs-switch directive?

Comment: BjornJohnson  - the reason I'm doing this is because I want to dynamically build forms from JSON data.   With that said, I don't see any other way to do this - do you?

Comment: Jony-Y : here is a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/billb123/nnkypoy9/15/

Comment: Can you just add the call to `.bootstrapSwitch()` inside a DOM ready function `$(function() {  $('.bs-switch').bootstrapSwitch(); })`.  [Demo in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/nnkypoy9/17/)

Comment: KyleMit - Hmm, that works in this case, but I think the application I'm building will be updating the HTML in-between page loads, including adding and removing radio button switches like this.  So I don't think your solution would work in that scenario, as it would only run once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manipulate DOM inside controller, use directive instead:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <switch></switch>
    </div>  
</div>  

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

    }
]).directive('switch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        'template': '<input type="checkbox" class="bs-switch" name="my-checkbox1" checked>',
        'link': function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).find('input').bootstrapSwitch();
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nnkypoy9/23/

Answer (score 2):

OK, this appears to work:

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngSanitize'
]);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce',
    function($scope, $sce) {

        // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093229/how-to-call-function-when-angular-watch-cycle-or-digest-cycle-is-completed
        var hasRegistered = false;
        $scope.$watch(function() {
            if (hasRegistered) return;
            hasRegistered = true;
            $scope.$$postDigest(function() {
                hasRegistered = false;
                $('.bs-switch').bootstrapSwitch();
            });
        });

        $scope.exampleHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(
            '<input type="checkbox" class="bs-switch" ' +
            '       name="my-checkbox2" checked>'
        );

    }
]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/billb123/nnkypoy9/19/

This is based on the following Stack Overflow question:

[how to call function when angular watch cycle or digest cycle is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093229/how-to-call-function-when-angular-watch-cycle-or-digest-cycle-is-completed)